# Check if array is in monotonic sequence

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to return true if the given array is in monotonic sequence. This is where I am so far but this function doesn't work as it should:

```
var isMonotone = function (arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function (previousValue, currentValue) {
    return previousValue <= currentValue;
  });
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/marcusdei/t0L1wryy/6/

This is not homework, I want to learn JS for my career. Thanks!

Comment: I tried this your `isMonotone` function with `console.log` for every `previousValue` and `currentValue` and found, that the `previousValue` in the second iteration is `true`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `every`, like so (just replace `[1, 2, 3, 4]` with `arr`)

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].every(function(e, i, a) { if (i) return e > a[i-1]; else return true; });
```

You'll need to adjust the > depending on whether you want to check for monotonically decreasing / increasing.

Comment: you don't need to use else when you have return in if statement.

Comment: Wouldn't that cause the first element to always return undefined (irrespective of whether it is smaller or larger)? For instance, the example in my answer would return false where it should return true. Cheers!

Comment: what i mean is, you can simply use `return true;` after if statement, no need to put it inside else.

Comment: This worked for me. I did have to adjust the operator to >= though. Thanks all!

Comment: by the way, what is meant by "if (i)"

Comment: for the very first element (index i = 0) you can't / don't need to compare it to the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution in JavaScript, expressed as a single line of code:

### Sort & Join

```js
var isMonotonic = (arr) => {
  return (
    arr.join`` == [...arr].sort((a, b) => a - b).join`` ||
    arr.join`` == [...arr].sort((a, b) => b - a).join``
  );
};


console.log(isMonotonic([8, 4, 2, 1]));
console.log(isMonotonic([8, 0, 5, 1]));
console.log(isMonotonic([7, 7, 7]));
```

### Every

```js
var isMonotonic = (arr) => {
  return (
    arr.every((v, i) => i === 0 || v <= arr[i - 1]) ||
    arr.every((v, i) => i === 0 || v >= arr[i - 1])
  );
};


console.log(isMonotonic([8, 4, 2, 1]));
console.log(isMonotonic([8, 0, 5, 1]));
console.log(isMonotonic([7, 7, 7]));
```

Answer (score 0):

I just needed a very performant implementation of this function (ES6).
This is what I came up with:

```
const is_monotonically_decreasing = (array) => {
    const n = array.length
    let i = 1
    while (i < n && array[i] - array[i - 1] < 0) {
        i++
    }
    return i === n
}
```

This saves the first iteration and using callbacks (smaller stack, less memory).
The behavior can changed by adjusting `array[i] - array[i - 1] < 0` accordingly.